# Counting the number of divisors of $1500$

Tags: combinatorics

I’m not sure how to frame the question in a more general form to make it more amenable for search, so here is the specific one: $2^n$, where $n$ is the number of prime factors gives the number of factors if all primes are unique, but I want to account for the three $5$'s and two $2$'s.

My current solution involves subtracting from $2^6$ the cases where the divisors contain less than the total number of the same primes, e.g. if $n$ divisors contains two fives, I’ll subtract $n\binom{3}{2}$. I think this will avoid double counting since these are separated into disjoint cases by the no. of primes.

Is this the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: Given $1500 = 2^2 \cdot 3^0 \cdot 5^3$, then the number of divisors is $(2+1)(0+1)(3+1)$. This is because for each prime power ranging from $0$ to $n$, there are $n+1$ possible ways to choose it, and that each number created this way is unique (fundamental theorem of algebra).

Comment: Just answered at the same time as you -  but note that it is 3^1.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $1500$ has prime factorization $2^2 \cdot 3^1 \cdot 5^3$, each factor of $1500$ has the form $2^a3^b5^c$, where $a \in \{0, 1, 2\}$, $b \in \{0, 1\}$, and $c \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$.  Since $a$ can be chosen in three ways, $b$ can be chosen in two ways, and $c$ can be chosen in four ways, $1500$ has $3 \cdot 2 \cdot 4 = 24$ factors.

If $n$ has prime factorization $p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}p_3^{a_3} \cdots p_k^{a_k}$, then each factor of $n$ has the form $n = p_1^{b_1}p_2^{b_2}p_3^{b_3} \cdots p_k^{b_k}$, where $b_i \in \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, a_i\}$ for $1 \leq i \leq k$.  Hence, $n$ has $(a_1 + 1)(a_2 + 1)(a_3 + 1) \cdots (a_k + 1)$ factors.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to say that a factor must be a product of three numbers:

a power of 2 - of which there are 3 possibilities 1,2 or 4

a power of 3 - of which there are 2 possibilities

a power of 5 - of which there are 4 possibilities

This gives $3.2.4=24$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$1500 = 2^2.3^1.5^3$$

In order to have a divisor of $1500$, you need to make choices on each power as to pick it or not to pick it. For example for powers of $5$ you have four choices namely picking no fives, one five, two fives, or three fives.

Multiplying all those choices you get $$ (3)(2)(4) = 24$$ possible divisors.